# Generate a QQ Plot for testing a geometrically distributed sample

Tags: r, statistics

I have a sample of n elements generated in R with

```
sim.geometric <- function(n)
{
    u <- runif(n)
    10*u/log(0.5)
}
```

for which i want to test its distribution, specifically if it indeed follows a geometric distribution. I want to generate a QQ PLot but have no idea how to. Can you help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A QQ-plot *should* be a straight line when compared to a "true" sample drawn from a geometric distribution with the same probability parameter. One gives two vectors to the functions which essentially compares their inverse ECDF's at each quantile. The fact that this particular sampling wasn't exactly straight is not a good signal that there is a problem. For one thing the duplicated points are not given enough weight because they are overlapping. This means the points in the right tail are getting extra importance that they don't deserve.

```
sim.res <- sim.geometric(100)
sim.rgeom <- rgeom(100, 0.3)
qqplot(sim.res, sim.rgeom)
```

Here I follow the lead of the authors of qqplot's help page (which results in flipping that upper curve around the line of identity):

```
png("QQ.png")
qqplot(qgeom(ppoints(100),prob=0.3), sim.res,
       main = expression("Q-Q plot for" ~~ {G}[n == 100]))
dev.off()
```

[image]

You can add a "line of good fit" by plotting a line through through the 25th and 75th percentile points for each distribution. (I added a jittering feature to this to get a better idea where the "probability mass" was located:)

```
sim.res <- sim.geometric(500)
qqplot(jitter(qgeom(ppoints(500),prob=0.3)), jitter(sim.res),
       main = expression("Q-Q plot for" ~~ {G}[n == 100]), ylim=c(0,max( qgeom(ppoints(500),prob=0.3),sim.res )),
xlim=c(0,max( qgeom(ppoints(500),prob=0.3),sim.res )))
 qqline(sim.res, distribution = function(p) qgeom(p, 0.3),
       prob = c(0.25, 0.75), col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DWin but what do you mean when you say it's not a successful attempt? A sample of 100 is very low to draw any conclusions. If i pump it up a bit i start seeing a straight line.

Comment: Well done. I may have jumped the gun on analyzing your efforts. I was applying heuristics for simulations that were acquired with Normal distributions, but maybe I need to use bigger numbers for discrete distributions?

Comment: Thank you very much for the input and for improving the answer @DWin. Would you say thge sample generated follows a geometric distribution? I think i'll perform a chisq.test to see.

Comment: In the absence of knowledge of exactly what "chi-square test" is being anticipated,  I suspect such a test is not the most powerful method.